# How to do a foreach equivalent in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a MySql query to print the last result of a build:

```
select * from buildresults where status in ('success','failed') 
and projectId=4 order by id desc limit 1
```

How can I run a for_each equivalent query for a set of projectIds? For each project I need to find whether the last build succeeded or failed. I don't want to take into account builds with running status.

I have another query returning the set of projectId.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what do you mean by "run a for_each"?

Comment: I have a set of projectIds. FOr each project I need to find whether the last build was success or failed. I don't want to take into account builds with running status.

Comment: Show your query returning the set of projectIds.

Comment: In SQL, you should generally try to avoid loops. You should explain what you want as an overall result ("I want to report the latest build status for complete builds for every project") and then write SQL to do that. SQL is meant to be a set-based language

Comment: I think I understand now. Darthvader just want to filter to the last occurance of each projectId.

Comment: Are we talking about MySQL or T-SQL? It is important to know that to provide an answer that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I am using MySQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you want is to limit each result to being the last of the projectId.

```
select * from buildresults
where status in ('success','failed')
and id = 
(
  select max(id) from buildresults as b2
  where b2.status in ('success','failed') and
  b2.projectId = buildresults.projectId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
    select * from buildresults 
where status in ('success','failed') 
    and projectId IN 
  (SELECT projectId from other_table where other condition)
  order by id desc
```

If you want both last success and failure you can do try this

```
SELECT MAX(id),status FROM buildresults
WHERE status IN ('success','failed')
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: I need to get only the last successful/failed build. I may get more with the query

Comment: just add `Limit 1` so you get only one result.

Comment: @darthvader I have added one more query for getting bots success and failure. Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from buildresults where status in ('success','failed') 
group by project_id order by id desc
```

You can then loop though all results with 1 per line.